# Low FPS in WebGL (working as 2d)

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl, frame-rate

I have script
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4Cqle1HMxo8LXl6YktuMF9EVWc/view?usp=sharing
It's working as WebGL 2D
When it draws 50 images (texture) -- FPS 60, but when it draws 150 and more -- FPS 20-30
Why?
How can I solve this problem with WebGL?
**UPD**
**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xo7metc8/1/)**
html

```
<canvas id="spirit_canvas"></canvas>
<div id="fps" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);color:#111;padding:1px 2px;font-size:10px;font-family:sans-serif;z-index:5"></div>
```

js

```
function WebGL2d(id)
{
    this._el = document.getElementById(id);
    this._gl = null;

    this._vertexShader = null;
    this._fragmentShader = null;
    this._program = null;

    this._p = {
        positionLocation: null,
        translationLocation: null,
        resolutionLocation: null,
        colorLocation: null,
        texCoordLocation: null,
        v_t: null
    };

    this._vertexShaderSrc = "\
        attribute vec2 a_position;\n\
        uniform vec2 u_resolution;\n\
        uniform vec2 u_translation;\n\
        attribute vec2 a_texCoord;\n\
        varying vec2 v_texCoord;\n\
        void main() {\n\
            vec2 position = a_position + u_translation;\n\
            vec2 zeroToOne = position / u_resolution;\n\
            vec2 zeroToTwo = zeroToOne * 2.0;\n\
            vec2 clipSpace = zeroToTwo - 1.0;\n\
            gl_Position = vec4(clipSpace * vec2(1, -1), 0, 1);\n\
            gl_PointSize = 2.;\n\
            v_texCoord = a_texCoord;\n\
        }\n\
    ";

    this._fragmentShaderSrc = "\
        precision mediump float;\n\
        uniform vec4 u_color;\n\
        uniform sampler2D u_image;\n\
        varying vec2 v_texCoord;\n\
        uniform int v_t;\n\
        void main() {\n\
            gl_FragColor = u_color;\n\
            if (v_t == 1) {\n\
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_image, v_texCoord);\n\
            }\n\
        }\n\
    ";

    this._canvas2d = null;
    this._canvas2dCache = null;
    this._canvasPathBuffer = [];
    this._isPointInPath = false;

    this.txtr = {};

    this._vertexBuffer = null;
    this._indexBuffer = null;
    this._uvBuffer = null;
    this._colorBuffer = null;

    // -------------------

    this.fillStyle = '#000';
    this.strokeStyle = '#000';
    this.lineWidth = 1;

    //----|||

    this._init();
}

WebGL2d.prototype = {

    _getCanvas: function(w,h)
    {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        canvas.width = w;
        canvas.height = h;
        return canvas.getContext("2d");
    },

    _hexToRgbArray: function (hex) {
        var shorthandRegex = /^#?([a-f\d])([a-f\d])([a-f\d])$/i;
        hex = hex.replace(shorthandRegex, function (m, r, g, b) {
            return r + r + g + g + b + b;
        });

        var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(hex);
        return result ? [
            parseInt(result[1], 16),
            parseInt(result[2], 16),
            parseInt(result[3], 16),
            1
        ] : [0,0,0,1];
    },

    _rgbToArray: function(rgba) {
        var result = /(?:rgb|rgba)\((\d+),\s?(\d+),\s?(\d+)(?:,\s?(\d+|\d.\d+))?\)/g.exec(rgba);
        if(result) {
            return result.slice(1).filter(isFinite).map(parseFloat);
        } else {
            return [0,0,0,1];
        }
    },

    _context: function () {
        var names = ["webgl","experimental-webgl"];
        var context = null;
        for (var ii = 0; ii < names.length; ++ii) {
            try {
                context = this._el.getContext(names[ii], {/*alpha: true, premultipliedAlpha: true, antialiasing: true*/});
            } catch (e) {
            }

            if (context) {
                break;
            }
        }

        if (context === null) {
            console.error('WebGL2d don\'t init');
            return;
        }

        this._gl = context;

        console.log('--');
    },

    _loadShader: function (src, type) {
        var shader = this._gl.createShader(type);
        this._gl.shaderSource(shader, src);
        this._gl.compileShader(shader);
        var compiled = this._gl.getShaderParameter(shader, this._gl.COMPILE_STATUS);

        if (!compiled) {
            lastError = this._gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader);
            console.error("*** Error compiling shader '" + shader + "':" + lastError);
            this._gl.deleteShader(shader);
            return null;
        }

        return shader;
    },

    _loadProgram: function (shaders) {
        var program = this._gl.createProgram();
        for (var i = 0; i < shaders.length; ++i) {
            this._gl.attachShader(program, shaders[i]);
        }

        this._gl.linkProgram(program);

        var linked = this._gl.getProgramParameter(program, this._gl.LINK_STATUS);
        if (!linked) {
            lastError = this._gl.getProgramInfoLog(program);
            log.error("Error in program linking:" + lastError);

            this._gl.deleteProgram(program);
            return null;
        }
        return program;
    },

    _init: function () {
        this._context();
        this._canvas2d = this._getCanvas(this._el.width,this._el.height);

        //this._gl.disable(this._gl.DEPTH_TEST);
        this._gl.enable(this._gl.BLEND);
        this._gl.blendFunc(this._gl.SRC_ALPHA, this._gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

        //this._gl.pixelStorei(this._gl.UNPACK_PREMULTIPLY_ALPHA_WEBGL, true);
        //this._gl.clearDepth (0.0);
        //this._gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
        //this._gl.clear(this._gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this._gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        //this._gl.clear(this._gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BITT);

        this._vertexShader = this._loadShader(this._vertexShaderSrc, this._gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
        this._fragmentShader = this._loadShader(this._fragmentShaderSrc, this._gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        this._program = this._loadProgram([this._vertexShader, this._fragmentShader]);
        this._gl.useProgram(this._program);

        this._p.positionLocation = this._gl.getAttribLocation(this._program, "a_position");
        this._p.translationLocation = this._gl.getAttribLocation(this._program, "u_translation");
        this._p.resolutionLocation = this._gl.getUniformLocation(this._program, "u_resolution");
        this._p.colorLocation = this._gl.getUniformLocation(this._program, "u_color");

        // texture
        this._p.texCoordLocation = this._gl.getAttribLocation(this._program, "a_texCoord");
        this._p.v_t = this._gl.getUniformLocation(this._program, "v_t");
        this._gl.uniform2f(this._p.resolutionLocation, this._el.width, this._el.height);


        this._initBuff();
    },

    _initBuff: function()
    {
        this._vertexBuffer = this._gl.createBuffer();
        this._indexBuffer = this._gl.createBuffer();
        this._uvBuffer = this._gl.createBuffer();
        this._colorBuffer = this._gl.createBuffer();
    },

    _drawArrTriangle: function(num)
    {
        this._gl.drawArrays(this._gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0,num);
    },

    // ==========

    _setColor: function (color)
    {
        this._gl.uniform1i(this._p.v_t, 0);

        if (!(color instanceof Array)) {

            if (color.indexOf('r') === 0 || color.indexOf('R') === 0) {
                color = this._rgbToArray(color);
            } else {
                color = this._hexToRgbArray(color);
            }
        }

        color[0] = Math.round(color[0] / 255 * 100)/100;
        color[1] = Math.round(color[1] / 255 * 100)/100;
        color[2] = Math.round(color[2] / 255 * 100)/100;

        this._gl.uniform4f(this._p.colorLocation, color[0], color[1], color[2], color[3]);
    },

    _buff: function (arr)
    {
        this._gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this._p.positionLocation);
        this._gl.bindBuffer(this._gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._vertexBuffer);
        this._gl.bufferData(this._gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array(arr), this._gl.DYNAMIC_DRAW);
        this._gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._p.positionLocation, 2, this._gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        this._gl.bindBuffer(this._gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
    },

    _buffTexture: function(image)
    {
        this._gl.bindBuffer(this._gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, this._uvBuffer);
        this._gl.bufferData(this._gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([
            0.0,  0.0,
            1.0,  0.0,
            0.0,  1.0,
            0.0,  1.0,
            1.0,  0.0,
            1.0,  1.0]), this._gl.STATIC_DRAW);

        this._gl.enableVertexAttribArray(this._p.texCoordLocation);
        this._gl.vertexAttribPointer(this._p.texCoordLocation, 2, this._gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        this._gl.bindBuffer(this._gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, null);
        if (!(image.src in this.txtr)) {
            this.txtr[image.src] = this._gl.createTexture();

            this._gl.bindTexture(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.txtr[image.src]);

            // Set the parameters so we can render any size image.
            this._gl.texParameteri(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_S, this._gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            this._gl.texParameteri(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._gl.TEXTURE_WRAP_T, this._gl.CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
            this._gl.texParameteri(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._gl.TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this._gl.LINEAR);
            this._gl.texParameteri(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this._gl.TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, this._gl.LINEAR);

            this._gl.texImage2D(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, 0, this._gl.RGBA, this._gl.RGBA, this._gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
        } else {
            this._gl.bindTexture(this._gl.TEXTURE_2D, this.txtr[image.src]);
        }

    },

    //--------------------------------------------

    fillRect: function(x,y,w,h,color,image)
    {
        var translation = [0, 0];
        translation[0] = x;
        translation[1] = y;

        var x2 = x + w;
        var y2 = h + y;

        this._buff(
            [
                x,y,
                x2,y,
                x,y2,

                x,y2,
                x2,y,
                x2,y2
            ]
        );

        if (!image) {
            if (color) {
                this._setColor(color);
            } else {
                this._setColor(this.fillStyle);
            }
        }

        this._drawArrTriangle(6);
    },

    strokeRect: function(x, y, w, h)
    {
        this.fillRect(
            x,
            y,
            w,
            this.lineWidth,
            this.strokeStyle
        );

        this.fillRect(
            (x + w - this.lineWidth),
            y,
            this.lineWidth,
            h,
            this.strokeStyle
        );

        this.fillRect(
            x,
            (y + h - this.lineWidth),
            w,
            this.lineWidth,
            this.strokeStyle
        );

        this.fillRect(
            x,
            y,
            this.lineWidth,
            h,
            this.strokeStyle
        );

    },

    clearRect: function(x, y, w, h)
    {
        //this._gl.clearDepth (1.0);
        this._gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1.0);
        //this._gl.clear(this._gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | this._gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        //this._gl.clear(this._gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    },

    beginPath: function(isPointInPath)
    {
        if (isPointInPath == true) {
            this._isPointInPath = true;
            this._canvas2d.beginPath();
        } else {
            this._isPointInPath = false;
            this._canvasPathBuffer = [];
        }
    },

    moveTo: function(x,y)
    {
        if (this._isPointInPath == true) {
            this._canvas2d.moveTo(x,y);
        } else {
            this._canvasPathBuffer.push([x,y]);
        }
    },

    lineTo: function(x,y)
    {
        if (this._isPointInPath == true) {
            this._canvas2d.lineTo(x,y);
        } else {
            this._canvasPathBuffer.push([x,y]);
        }
    },

    fill: function()
    {

        if (this._canvasPathBuffer.length == 4) {

            this._buff(
                [
                    this._canvasPathBuffer[0][0], this._canvasPathBuffer[0][2],
                    this._canvasPathBuffer[1][0], this._canvasPathBuffer[1][3],
                    this._canvasPathBuffer[2][0], this._canvasPathBuffer[2][4],

                    this._canvasPathBuffer[2][0], this._canvasPathBuffer[2][5],
                    this._canvasPathBuffer[3][0], this._canvasPathBuffer[3][6],
                    this._canvasPathBuffer[0][0], this._canvasPathBuffer[0][7]
                ]
            );

            this._setColor(this.fillStyle);

            this._drawArrTriangle(6);
        }

    },

    closePath: function()
    {
        if (this._isPointInPath == true) {
            this._canvas2d.closePath();
        }
    },

    isPointInPath: function(x,y)
    {
        return this._canvas2d.isPointInPath(x,y);
    },

    text: function (text,x,y,size,color,fontStyle,fontFamily,borderColor)
    {
        return false;
    },

    fillText: function(text,x,y,maxWidth)
    {
        return false;
    },

    drawImage: function(img,x,y, w, h)
    {
        this._gl.uniform1i(this._p.v_t, 1);
        this._buffTexture(img);
        this.fillRect(x,y,w,h,false,true);
    }

};

function microtime()
{
    return new Date().getTime();
}

function round(s,exp) {
    exp = exp || 0;
    return Math.round(s * Math.pow(10,exp)) / Math.pow(10,exp);
}


window.requestAnimFrame = (function(){
    return  window.requestAnimationFrame       ||
        window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
        window.mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
        window.oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
        window.msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        function(callback, element){
            window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        };
})();


var canvas;
var image;
var fpsLastCalledTime;

var height = 400;
var width = 700;

function main() {
    var $el = $('#spirit_canvas');

    $('body').css('width',(width + 'px'));
    $el.css({'width':(width + 'px'),'height':(height + 'px')}).attr('width',width).attr('height',height);

    canvas = new WebGL2d('spirit_canvas');

    image = new Image();
    image.src = "data:image/png;base64,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";
    image.onload = function() {
        play();
    }
}

function play()
{
    //this.time = microtime();

    canvas.clearRect();
    draw();
    drawFps();

    requestAnimFrame(play.bind(window));
}

drawFps = function()
{
    var fps;

    if(!fpsLastCalledTime) {
        fpsLastCalledTime = microtime();
        fps = 0;
    } else {
        fps = round(1000/(microtime() - fpsLastCalledTime));
        fpsLastCalledTime = microtime();
    }
    $('#fps').html('fps: ' + fps);

};

function draw()
{
    canvas.fillRect(0,0,width,height,'#eee');

    var __x = 0;
    var __y = 0;
    var __h = 37;
    var __w = 26;

    var x, y, h, w;

    for(var i = 0; i < 200; ++i) {

        if (i % 26 == 0) {
            __y = __y + __h;
            __x = 0;
        } else {
            __x = __x + __w;
            //__y = __y;
        }

        h = __h;
        w = __w;
        x = __x;
        y = __y;

        //canvas.fillRect(x,y, w, h,'#050');

        canvas.drawImage(image,x,y, w, h);

    }
}


main();
```

Comment: Show us some code here.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xo7metc8/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you only want to call `gl.bufferData` and `gl.texImage2d` at init time. AFAICT you're calling them for every draw call.

Comment: Yeah, if you run this through Chrome's profiler, you can see that 65% of the time is being spent inside the _buffTexture function

Comment: Likewise, your fillrect call buffers a new object every frame - again you only need to do this once (or at least only do it if your values have changed.)  Better still, just have a 1x1 sized triangle array, and use a matrix passed to the shader to resize it.